# Entity Framework - Linq - Unable to create a constant value of type ‘System.Object’. Only primitive types

Tags: linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

I have a method to build an expression for a linq query for a given type, property, and value. This works wonderfully as long as the property on the type is NOT nullable. Here is the example I am working from ([http://www.marcuswhitworth.com/2009/12/dynamic-linq-with-expression-trees](http://www.marcuswhitworth.com/2009/12/dynamic-linq-with-expression-trees/)) I am calling the Equals method on the property. However I have discovered that the Equals method for Nullable types takes an Object as a parameter instead of the Nullable type. I attempted to use GetValueOrDefault to hide the null values but EF doesn't support that method. As a simple example the following code will throw an error:

```
decimal? testVal = new decimal?(2100);
        var test = (from i in context.Leases where i.AnnualRental.Equals(testVal) select i).ToList();
```

However if you use == instead of the Equals() method it will work OK. I am not sure how to convert the code to use == instead of Equals() however. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would `==` not work in this scenario?

Comment: I'll have ti ask the same question as cdhowie, why would you use Equals when == pretty much does the same thing? var test = context.Leases.Where(l => l.AnnualRental == testVal).ToList(); should work just fine?

Answer (score 3):

If you say `==`, you generate a `BinaryExpression` with NodeType as `ExpressionType.Equal`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361179.aspx

If you say `.Equals(x)`, you generate a `MethodCallExpression`.  The `MethodCallExpression`s that LinqToEntities may translate into Sql is a limitted list (for example none of your own undecorated methods are in that list).  `Nullable<T>.Equals(x)` is apparently not on that list.

Don't say `.Equals(x)` to LinqToEntities.